# SQL - Preventing duplication in a join, or intersecting on chosen columns

Tags: sql, join

If I have two tables, table A and table B. Neither table has a key. Columns A.2 and A.3 share values respectively with B.2 and B.3. I want to make an intersection of these columns while retaining the columns A.1 and B.1 in the output. It does not matter which value from A.1 and B.1 end up being chosen. Is there a way of doing that?

[image] [image]

I have tried to make a join but the values in B.1 lead to duplication.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.2 = B.2 AND A.3 = B.3
```

[image]

Ideally the end result would look something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH B_DEDUPE AS (
SELECT MIN(B.1) AS "1", B.2, B.3
FROM B
GROUP BY B.2, B.3
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B_DEDUPE C ON A.2 = C.2 AND A.3 = C.3
```